# How can I remove extraneous XP gained from glitch?

Tags: borderlands-2

I was playing multiplayer on Borderlands 2 the other day with some random dude on my Mac, and without asking me, he did something to my character which changed me from lvl 34 to 50 and gave me a ton of skill points, which he says is a glitch. Now, I'm unable to gain XP and am stuck as a lvl 50 character. This really annoys me and I'm desperate for a way to fix this glitch so that I am lvl 34 again.

Does anyone know of a way to undo this?

Comment: Ouch.  Unless you have a backup of your character file, I don't think there's much you can do.

Comment: Do you have any of the DLC? If not, your character is capped at level 50.

Answer (score 3):

The way people set up your character's level is using a cheat engine trainer which can change the userdata of anyone in their game. If they've joined your game there is a small chance that they can still change your character data.
The way to undo this is to use an inventory editor or another Cheat Engine  trainer for Borderlands 2. The inventory editor that I use is called "Gibbed" which you can download [here](http://blog.gib.me/2014/07/15/borderlands-2-save-editor-revision-237/). There is also the Cheat Engine trainer which I have no link for currently so your best bet is to use Gibbed to load your save file and change your player level. I hope you manage to get your profile back to normal since this has happened to me a lot of times.